# Hibernate Tools Indigo : Property view doesn't display result item correctly

Tags: hibernate, properties, hibernate-tools

i'm running Indigo SR1 20110916-0149 with Hibernate Tools Version: 3.4.0.v20111213-1944-H40-M5.

Everything seems to work fine but the Properties view doesn't display the result item details when clicking on one of the result list in Hibernate Query Result tab.

I don't think is due to nature of my Entities since similar queries where displaying everything correctly even relationship parent/child etc..with '+' sign on which you could click to expand collection.

I've looked around and couldn't find anything helpfull.
I saw a similar question in myeclipse forum which as unresolved.

It seems to be a regression.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with Indigo Hibernate Tools M5 (milestone 5) and beta1.
Found that M4 (milestone 4) is working, so i filled a bug report on jboss tools issue tracker about this issue (regression).
[JBIDE-11343](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-11343)

So try to use milestone 4, it's working for me.

Comment: Ok it's marked as resolved and the nightly build (TRUNK) version resolves it.

Thanks a lot for helping to fix this out Melo !